# How much Omega-6 does sprat have?

Tags: fish

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, but I couldn't find this information, I looked for two days. How much omega-6 do sprats have, does anyone know?

Comment: This question has a close vote as a request for nutritional advice. I firmly disagree with the close vote as the question does not ask for opinions about what is and isn't healthy. It's no different than asking how much protein is in bread flour or how much Vitamin C to add to guacamole for my party tomorrow. The question is objective and precisely answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fish contain very little n-6 (Omega-6 aka linoleic) fatty acids by nature. Most of the n-6 fats are contributed by vegetable sources during processing, such as vegetable oils used in coatings or pre-cooking. The amount of n-6 fats will depend on how the fish is processed and in which oil.

The US National Library of Medicine has a brief article at [this page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23110317). Info on n-3 and n-9 fatty acids in sprats can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24693715)